# SharePoint Online: Webpart that opens links in the same tab in modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online

Links embedded on webparts open files in a new tab. Is there a customized web part available that will open files/links on the same tab?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You may have more luck with sharepoint questions on the [sharepoint stackexchange site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Classic version, if you use text web part it will allow you to add links and those links will open in same tab. you can tick or un tick the option in the text window.
I hope this make sense to you.
Cheers